# VFP - SQLEXEC está retornando campo DATE como CHAR

Tags: string, data, sql-server-2005

Estou dando suporte em uma aplicação "legado" escrita em VFP, que utiliza tabelas DBF e migrando agora para SQL Server.

Criei uma tabela de testes no SQL, que contém campos de alguns tipos básicos, para poder trabalhar com a migração, efetuando testes de pesquisa, inclusão, alteração, etc.

A tabela tem o seguinte formato:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[teste](
  [CpTexto] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [CpData] [datetime] NULL,
  [CpDataTime] [datetime] NULL,
  [CpValor] [numeric](15, 5) NULL,
  [CpInteiro] [int] NULL,
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

À partir do VFP estou efetuando consultas utilizando SQLEXEC, com o seguinte sintaxe:

```
lnNumConex = 1
lnSQL = [SELECT * FROM TESTE]
lnTmpCur = [CurTESTE]
= SQLEXEC(lnNumConex,lnSQL,lnTmpCur)
```

Quando faço o SQLEXEC, o SQL devolve um cursor, com todos os campos contidos na tabela TESTE, porém o campo cpDATA ao invés de vir um campo no formato DATE, ele retorna como um campo CHAR.

Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui descobrir o que estava errado.

Por default, a conexão SQL utilizava o driver nativo do SQL Server, instalado no pc
 O String de Conexão estava assim:
`Driver={SQL Server};Server=XXX;Database=YYY;UID=fulano;PWD=senha;]`, 
e quando passei a utilizar o client mais atual que tenho (o client 10.0), tudo passou a funcionar bem.